# Compare variables declared in Snowflake Stored procedure

Tags: snowflake-task

I got a stored procedure as below
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SP12
(argument1 VARCHAR,argument2 VARCHAR
)

```
if (argument1 <> argument2) { return N1 } else { return N2}
```

The issue is iam getting error while comparing argument1 <> argument2 (need to compare not equal to).
Is this correct method.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

is the the complete code for your Stored Procedure or is it just a snippet? If it is the full code then I suggest that you read the documentation again: [CREATE PROCEDURE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-procedure.html)

1. You need a RETURNS statement in the header
2. How are you declaring/assigning values to N1 and N2?

If these suggestions don't help then please provide the full SP Code (if this is just a snippet) and also the error message you are getting